# Can't autowire method in spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to test a Login with JWT but everytime I try to test this method it gives me a:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "it.security.jwt.JwtTokenUtil.generateToken(org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails)" because "this.jwtTokenUtil" is null
```

The class I use is this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AuthenticationRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws Exception {
        JwtUser userDetails;
        userDetails = JwtUserFactory.create("user", null);
        String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        Assert.assertNotNull(token);
    }
}
```

I also tried with mock and other tests stuff but nothing it worked for me.

Any idea of what I missed?

or anything to improve my login test

Answer (score 0):

Your `JwtTokenUtil` class might not be registered as a bean in the Spring Container, so there's no way it can be injected as a dependency to another classes using `@Autowired`.

In order for a bean to be managed by Spring, you have either to:

make it a component, using `@Component` or its derivatives -- `@Service` and `@Repository`:

```java
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil {
    // your class' fields and methods
}
```

... or to make it a return type of a method annotated with `@Bean`, which *indicates that a method produces a bean to be managed by the Spring container* (definition from the [Spring's API documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html)). Often, a method like that is declared in a `@Configuration` class, because it's loaded as soon as your application starts, while the Spring's Application Context searches for beans to register to the Spring Container:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil() {
        return new JwtTokenUtil();
    }
}
```

Obs.: I would like to ask you if you already did it, but unfortunately I cannot add a comment to your question because I don't have 50 reputation yet. I hope it helps you.